# Unusual Hibernate inheritance mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, mapping

I've got a curious puzzle with an object-relational mapping, using Java and Hibernate.

We have an existing schema that looks something like this:

```
create table foo (id int8, /* ... */ primary key (id));
create table bar (id int8, foo int8, /* ... */ primary key (id));
alter table bar add constraint fk_foobar foreign key (foo) references foo;
```

Normally, you would map this using a `ManyToOne` relationship.

```
class Foo { /* ... */ }
class Bar { private Foo foo; /* ... */ }
```

But one of the guys on my team wants to map this into an inheritance relationship:

```
class Foo { /* ... */ }
class Bar extends Foo { /* ... */ }
```

Is there any way to pull this off with Hibernate?

*Edit:* The important point is that the table `bar` has a foreign key column `foo`, which is distinct from `bar`'s identity column.

Comment: I use NHibernate (port of Hibernate) with C# and the answer is yes. There are examples in the NHibernate docs and Im sure the same exists for Hibernate

Comment: did you solve your issue? please provide feedback.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no.  I bet Hibernate is hard-wired so that if you have an inheritance relationship, the primary key in the derived class's table has to be a foreign key to the base class's table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only map this as an inheritance relationship, if Bar *is a* Foo.  Otherwise, you should use composition.
But, offcourse, I do not know the context, so I don't know whether mapping these classes as a sub and base class is correct.

Anyway, yes, it is possible to do this.
Check [the different possibilities to create an inheritance relationship in Hibernate.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)

For instance, you could use the Joined Subclass scenario here:

```
<class name="Foo" table="Foos">
   <joined-subclass="Bar" table="Bars">
   </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

Comment: The actual use case is sort of a gray area.  Bar provides additional data about Foo.  In that way, you can think about it as Bar is-a Foo.  But there may be multiple objects providing additional data about the same Foo.  That leans more toward Bar has-a Foo.

The mapping you give doesn't map into the existing schema.  The bar table has an id column distinct from the foo foreign key column.

Comment: This is a composition for me because it is one-to-many. You can't have multiple Bars for the same Foo using inheritance. Think about Inheritance Mapping for all the "additional Info" objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Foo { .. }
```

But do it only if it is *logical* to be inheritance. I.e. if it is `Dog extends Animal`, and NOT in case it is `User extends Group`